# Was this brief image in episode 5.07 of The Handmaid's an allusion to Charlotte's Web?

Tags: reference, the-handmaids-tale

In episode 5.07 (No Man's Land) of the TV series adaptation of [*The Handmaid's Tale*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Handmaid%27s_Tale_(TV_series)) things take a U-Turn when

### MAJOR SPOILERS AHEAD

> Serena is taken to June and she injures Ezra to escape the Wheelers and
>  flees with June, only to go into labor, as June's reckless driving
>  leads to a flat tire and getting stuck in the mud in No Man's Land.
>  Eventually off the side of the road there is a barn,  where June
>  eventually helps Serena give birth. I also think it's important to
>  note the episode also features a flashback to when Serena and June
>  share a moment in Gilead when a handmaid dies while giving birth,
>  which is cruelly and casually handled -- And that in the previous
>  episode Mr. Putnam was executed for his crimes against Esther, and as
>  longtime viewers know, this is also justice for Ganine, who wanted her
>  daughter with Putnam to be named "Charlotte"...

There is one scene however in the barn where there is shot of a beautiful spider web up in the rafters, above where the characters are (*I'm looking for a screen cap to add*). Given the juxtapositions to birth and/or life and death in the two parallel stories being told in the episode, I was wondering if the spider web was an intentional allusion to the children's novel [*Charlotte's Web*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charlotte%27s_Web) by E.B. White?